# MySQL fields in URL

Tags: php, mysql, select

**Is there a way to call field rows in a URL without using the column name??**

So I currently have a posting site where users can select category or subcategories of choice from drop downs, how it's currently setup my site outputs links to the categories chosen such as..

```
topics.php?category=Food&sub_cat=Pies
topics.php?sub_cat=Pies
```

This allows users to go to either one of the links, or both

```
topics.php?category=Food&sub_cat=Pies
```

To give more functionality I am looking at adding textboxes instead of drop downs, the problem is users will more than likely enter the data in different boxes than other users, ie.

User 1.  catbox: **Food** subcatbox: Pies
User 2.  catbox: Pies subcatbox: **Food**

So in this case my current URL system won't return accurate results, so my question is would there be a way where "category" or "subcategory" could be replaced and just put the results together without them being listed in 2-5 different fields therefore not returning all the results that = to that value? "food" or "pie" in this example.

```
topics.php?xxx=Food&xxx=Pies
```

or
    topics.php?xxx=Pies&xxx=Food

Looking at So homepage if you click "php" it will put php in the URL, click mysql and it will put "php+mysql" that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parent child method in your database.
your table would be like this

id - parent_id - category_name - depth
when you want to insert a data to your table it's depth will be one plus it's parent depth

when someone post to your page you first take query witch of the inputs has most depth then that will be your subcategory.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my problem is that all the fields(possible 3-5 text boxes) are just as relevant as the others, kinda like how on this site we can tag words, [ php ] [ mysql ], hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Calling field rows via parameters in your URL may be a very bad idea. It's a perfect way to allow a massive SQL injection attack. So, the answer is probably "yes, but HOLY MOLY PLEASE DON'T!"

Now it *may* be that your code is parsing these out on the back end and protecting them via any of a variety of methods, I can't tell from the amount of code posted.

Comment: thanks for your input, I was only using the row names as I wasn't aware of another way to do it, could you suggest a way? and is my question not possible? I need a wild card that will pull the data from anywhere from 3-5 fields :(

Comment: I just looked at SO home page and if you hover over the tags they are just /tag/php  for example, I'm looking for a way to call 1 or multiple fields but the same data value could be in any of the 3-5 columns.